# Openstack Devstack installation error : g-api did not start in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: openstack, openstack-glance

I'm installing openstack using All-In-One Single Machine setup, I run stack.sh script for devstack setup. On starting glance service I'm getting following error on my console:

```
++::                                        curl -g -k --noproxy '*' -s -o /dev/null -w '%{http_code}' http://10.10.20.10/image
+::                                        [[ 503 == 503 ]]
+::                                        sleep 1
+functions:wait_for_service:485            rval=124
+functions:wait_for_service:490            time_stop wait_for_service
+functions-common:time_stop:2310           local name
+functions-common:time_stop:2311           local end_time
+functions-common:time_stop:2312           local elapsed_time
+functions-common:time_stop:2313           local total
+functions-common:time_stop:2314           local start_time
+functions-common:time_stop:2316           name=wait_for_service
+functions-common:time_stop:2317           start_time=1602763779096
+functions-common:time_stop:2319           [[ -z 1602763779096 ]]
++functions-common:time_stop:2322           date +%s%3N
+functions-common:time_stop:2322           end_time=1602763839214
+functions-common:time_stop:2323           elapsed_time=60118
+functions-common:time_stop:2324           total=569
+functions-common:time_stop:2326           _TIME_START[$name]=
+functions-common:time_stop:2327           _TIME_TOTAL[$name]=60687
+functions:wait_for_service:491            return 124
+lib/glance:start_glance:480               die 480 'g-api did not start'
+functions-common:die:198                  local exitcode=0
+functions-common:die:199                  set +o xtrace
[Call Trace]
./stack.sh:1306:start_glance
/opt/stack/devstack/lib/glance:480:die
[ERROR] /opt/stack/devstack/lib/glance:480 g-api did not start
Error on exit
World dumping... see /opt/stack/logs/worlddump-2020-10-15-121040.txt for details
neutron-dhcp-agent: no process found
neutron-l3-agent: no process found
neutron-metadata-agent: no process found
neutron-openvswitch-agent: no process found
```

I also tried to increase timeout duration but then also it failed and also verifyied devstack@g-api.service is in active state. Can someone let me know what is the exect reason behind this issue and how to resolve it.

Comment: What happens when you try to start g-api manually by doing: systemctl start g-api?

Comment: To start the Glance API, you need to run `systemctl start devstack@g-api`. I have experienced *g-api* not starting because the host had not enough memory. Or you may have run *stack.sh* earlier without completing it, then run it again. You can check the log with `journalctl -e -u devstack@g-api` and also try `systemctl status devstack@g-api`.

Comment: g-api service is running & active without any issue, still the same issue persist as above

Answer (score 1):

The only solution is to reload the entire system, including the os